# mysql update if exists otherwise update when I don't have the unique key

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

A similar question has been asked before, and the answer was to use

```
INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

However, this requires the duplicate key to have unique property. What if I don't and cannot have unique property?

The detail is as follows:
I have a tablewith 4 columns:

```
id  col2 col3 count
```

If both `col2` and `col3` values exist, then increase count, otherwise insert this item. How could I do that with one MySQL query?

**UPDATE**

I realized only after posting this question that I can set unqiue key for more than one column. For example, if I do not want to have col2 and col3 duplicate, I can execute the following sql to make the combined column a unique one:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE unique_index (`col2`, `col3`);
```

Comment: Your question not cleared. So please enter output as what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use insert on duplicate  [MYSQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,`count`) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=(col2+col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you want this?

```
    IF EXISTS(--Query to check for the existence of your condition here)
    BEGIN
      --UPDATE HERE
    END ELSE
    BEGIN
      --INSERT HERE
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Dainy,

I think you are looking to insert record if it doesn't exist then to update specific column value, right..?

And for that, you require to create a procedure like this:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure update_or_insert()
begin
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col2 = 'something2' AND col3 = 'something3') THEN
    UPDATE tablename SET count = count + 1;
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO tablename (col2, col3, count) VALUES ('something2', 'something3', 'something4');
  END IF;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

and call that procedure like:

```
call update_or_insert();
```

Hope this helps you out.

Thanks!